# how to get value of zooms in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, react-hooks

Learning React by coding, here i'm using 'react-zoom-pan-pinch' for zoomIn/zoomOut by clicking buttons, but it is also possible to zoomIn and zoomOut using mouse scroll wheel, and i want that value is it possible ? so when i zoomIn or zoomOut using mouse scroll wheel i want that value which shows i have zoomed in or zoomed out and how much.

Demo of code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/qmn69?file=/src/index.js:139-159

code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
`;
const Box = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: ${props => (props.backColor ? props.backColor : "blue")};
  margin: 5px;
`;
const Toolbox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 2em;
  }
`;
function App() {
  const onClick = () => {
    alert("onClick : open popup");
  };
  const onContextMenu = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("onContextMenu : show info");
  };

  const renderBoxes = () => {
    let i;
    let arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      arr.push(
        <Box key={"b" + i} onClick={onClick} onContextMenu={onContextMenu} />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"r" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="red"
        />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"y" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="yellow"
        />
      );
      arr.push(
        <Box
          key={"g" + i}
          onClick={onClick}
          onContextMenu={onContextMenu}
          backColor="gray"
        />
      );
    }
    return arr;
  };
  return (
    <TransformWrapper
      defaultScale={1}
      defaultPositionX={200}
      defaultPositionY={100}
    >
      {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, positionX, positionY, ...rest }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Toolbox>
            <button onClick={zoomIn}>+</button>
            <button onClick={zoomOut}>-</button>
            <button onClick={resetTransform}>x</button>
          </Toolbox>
          <TransformComponent>
            <Container>{renderBoxes()}</Container>
          </TransformComponent>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </TransformWrapper>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: any help is appreciated !

Comment: Mouse scroll wheel zooming is ”react-zoom-pan-pinch” feature so there is some way to get that value (that which you linked is different and complicated)

Comment: Check "Values returned from TransformWrapper component" from https://reactjsexample.com/react-library-to-support-easy-zoom-pan-pinch-on-various-html-dom-elements. This might help.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-zoom-pan-pinch-forked-gsd7jf?file=/src/index.js. I modified your code and it's showing the zoom level. Have a look and let me know if this is what you  want.

Comment: Im not getting anything when zooming in console.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245997/discussion-between-suprabhat-kumar-and-walee).

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245997/discussion-between-suprabhat-kumar-and-walee

Comment: @SuprabhatKumar  im not home right now so tried that on my phone and got nothing on console

Comment: @SuprabhatKumar hi your code is working, but its not working on latest release of react-zoom-pan-pinch which is version : 2.1.3, i need it to work on latest

Comment: can't you downgrade it or look on internet bcoz now i am busy. I shall search and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for version 3 of `react-zoom-pan-pinch`.

Add the callback `onTransformed` prop to `TransformWrapper` component.

```
    <TransformWrapper
      defaultScale={1}
      defaultPositionX={200}
      defaultPositionY={100}
      onTransformed={(e) => handleTransform(e)}
      >
```

The `handleTransform` function is defined as follows:

```
  function handleTransform(e){
    console.log(e.instance.transformState.scale); // output scale factor
  }
```

Now each time you zoom in/out, the scale factor will be outputted.

Here's the type of `onTransformed` so you access information other than the scale factor:

```
(ref: ReactZoomPanPinchRef, scale: number, positionX: number, positionY: number ) => void
```

## References

https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page